# How can you create Refs after the component has mounted in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

My case requires that I use React.createRef() for each time picker I have (there is a certain functionality in the time pickers that can be only used through Refs).

When the page is mounted, I have initially 2 time pickers. All works well when I have only two, but my work is ruined because I am required to Add/Remove Time Pickers using buttons. So I am able to add the time pickers easily.

But now my question is how do I create the refs ? My declaration for React.createRef() is in the Constructor(){} for the first 2 refs.
The question is where do I instantiate the refs for the time pickers that are added onClick ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your time picker in an another component, create the ref there and perform the work that requires a ref inside of that components then forwarding the result via props (you can pass a function via a prop).

For example, you could give each component an unique ID (uuid does a great job of that), pass that via a prop, pass a value and pass a function that accepts an ID and a value, then call that function whenever a result from the ref is obtained.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, but it requires you to have a unique identifier per component that should not be the index. (Cause this can change)

Pseudo Code

```
class Wrapper extends Component {
   construct() {
      ...
      this.refsById = {}
   }
   getRefOrCreate(id) {
    if(_has(this.refsById[id]) {
       return this.refsById[id];
    } else {
       this.refsById[id] = React.createRef();
       return this.refsById[id];
    } 
   } 

  onClickHandler(value, id) {
      const ref = this.refs[id];
      const { onClick } = this.props;
 }

  render(){
     // Here you need to know how many pickers you need, and their id
    const { pickersInformationArray} = this.props; 
    return (
      <div> { pickersInformationArray.map((id) => <TimePicker ref={this.getRefOrCreate(id);} onClick={(value) => { this.onClickHandler(value, id); } } )} </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
Let me first say that I was using the method of creating ref in the constructor in my incorrect solution

```
 class DummyClass extends Component {
     constructor(){ 
         this.timePickerRef = React.createRef();
     }
 }

 render() {
    let timers = array.map( index => {
         <TimePicker
              ref={timepicker => timePickerRef = timepicker} 
              value={00}
              onChange={(data) => 
                      {this.handleTimePcikerValueChange(data, index);}}
         />
    } 
   return (
         timers
   )
 }
}
```

what I instead did was the following

disregard and remove this.timePickerRef = React.createRef() since it will no longer be necessary

while the code in handleTimePcikerValueChange & render will be as follows:

```
handleTimePcikerValueChange = (value, index) => {
  // do whatever manipulation you need
  // and access the ref using the following
  this[`timePicker_${index}`] 
}
render() {
    let timers = array.map( index => {
         <TimePicker
              ref={timepicker => this[`timePicker_${index}`] = timepicker} 
              value={00}
              onChange={(data) => 
                      {this.handleTimePcikerValueChange(data, index);}}
         />
    } 
   return (
         timers
   )
 }
```

I didn't post the code that handle adding time pickers because it is irrelevant.
I would like to thank those who responded !

Comment: That's basically what my solution does without the utilization of React.createRef()